# Raspberry Pi 4 not outputting to 4K

Tags: pi-4, video

My new Raspberry Pi 4B doesn’t seem to support 4K resolution out of the box.

I have tried two different 4K native screens and two micro-HDMI to HDMI cables, and neither works. However, if I connect a screen with a lower resolution, the boot loader appears fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pi4 should allow 4K 30Hz out of the box. Can your screen do that. If you want 60Hz you need to enable it https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#hdmi_enable_4kp60-raspberry-pi-4-only